# What value should be used for Audio Unit Hosting Temporary Exception(OS X implementation of App Sandbox)?

Tags: macos, core-audio, sandbox

My question is related to another post 
    [Core Audio doesn't seem to work when using sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318480/core-audio-doesnt-seem-to-work-when-using-sandboxing). But since I don't have enough reputation to comment on that post I have to answer a new question. I have the same issue as the person posting that question, namely Core Audio causes a problem when I enable sandboxing: about to throw -3000: AUGraphOpen. The solution is to add

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.audio-unit-host
```

to the entitlements plist. I get this; however, I am not sure what type and values I should use for this key. If I am correct the type should be string or array of strings, but I have no idea what to set for the value.

I know that my question may seem very trivial to some people, but I searched a lot and read the apple documentation, but I couldn't find any example of a value for this specific key. So, A little example will be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to my own question; I tried different things, and finally, type Boolean with value yes worked.